# Firebase Messaging Service and Firebase InstanceId Service cannot be resolved to a type in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Here I am developing FCM - Push Notifications. I am new to FCM
feature. I am getting errors like this Firebase Messaging Service and
Firebase InstanceId Service cannot be resolved to a type in Eclipse. Here 
I am using Eclipse IDE. I have added firebase-client-android-2.5.2.jar, 
updated Repository and Google Play Services library.

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private static final String TAG = "StartingAndroid";

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

        //It is optional
        Log.e(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

        Log.d("TestTag","remoteMessage: "+remoteMessage);

        Log.e(TAG, "Notification Message Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());

        //Calling method to generate notification
        sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle(),remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    }

    //This method is only generating push notification
    private void sendNotification(String title, String messageBody) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class); 
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
               // .setSmallIcon(R.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(messageBody)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you include your dependencies in your question, that would help determine if you are using the correct libraries. Also firebase-client-android-2.5.2.jar will not contain the new Firebase v2 classes.